# How can I access the logged in user when using socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, passport.js

In all my routes it's pretty easy to grab the logged in user with passport.js and stuff by just going req.user.username (to grab the username), but there's a page which solely uses websockets and I'm wondering how I can figure out the logged in users username.

I've searched around and found a couple fixes but they don't really work well. Initially what I tried to do was have a variable that grabs the username as soon as someone loads the page, idk what I was thinking since it'd just get reset each time someone else makes a request to the page. Then I noticed someone say to just have an invisible div element on the front-end and send that with the data when I'm emitting using sockets and this works but it's quite unsafe since someone can just edit the code if they know how to get into dev tools and mess with things.

So do you guys have any easily implementable fixes?

Comment: My guess is that socket.io has no knowledge of the logged-in user at all.  It's operating solely within the context of your browser session.

Comment: When a user logs in, generate a random token server-side for the user and store it on the client as cookie / in localStorage. When they connect via socket.io, let them send the token, that way the socket server can use the token to look up the user.

Comment: If the websocket connection is running on the same domain and port as the website, you should receive the same session cookies.

Comment: @ChrisG That's smart! I should be able to implement that pretty easily. I'm using Mongo as my db so each account has a unique id, I can just store that unique id in localstorage and send that out with my sockets. As an aside, can y'all think of any security issues with this method or why this method would be 'bad' in any case?

Comment: Also, I'm passing the userID from the backend simply like so `res.render("index", {userID: userid});`, but how can I access this in my JS file? Only my index file can access this variable. Does this mean I need to use script tags in my index file or is there some other way.

Comment: I don't see a security issue; an attacker would have to guess another user's ID. As for transferring data to the client: either echo script tags or use AJAX / fetch().

Answer (score 0):

(old but could help somebody else)

If you're using passport and socket.io, I think this library should be the way to go to get current user's data:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport.socketio